# Why a pointer to user-defined object does not hold the same address in the memory as the user-definded object itself

Tags: objective-c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am leaning blocks In objective-c, I wanted to understand the concept behind the pointers from the perspective of objective-c.
given the code below, I expected that the the 3 statement to display the same result or at least the sam memory address. At least because, the pointer

```
meAsImpl refers/points/observs the memory location of the user-defined object MeAsImpl
Hence, the 3 NSLog statement should display the same results
```

The out put of the code are as follows:

```
 <MeAsImpl: 0x600000194120>
<MeAsImpl: 0x60000019f240>
<MeAsImpl: 0x60000019f240>
```

Please let me know why the first value differs to the subsequent  two values

**code**:

```
    MeAsImpl *meAsImpl = [[MeAsImpl alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", meAsImpl);
    NSLog(@"%@", MeAsImpl.alloc);
    NSLog(@"%@", MeAsImpl.alloc.init);
```

Comment: Are you learning Objective-C for work?

Comment: `alloc` and `init` are methods, you should call them via the square bracket notation. Don't abuse the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `alloc`, new memory address allocates for the caller. `init` just initialized the already allocated memory, so the address wont change on `init`

You use `alloc` two times, you get two memory addresses.

Comment: i intentionally removed the comment, as i got ur point now..i did not realized that very 1st statement     MeAsImpl *meAsImpl = [[MeAsImpl alloc] init];

Comment: but, i have a quest. please..after the statement     MeAsImpl *meAsImpl = [[MeAsImpl alloc] init];
how can i display the memot´ry address of MeAsImpl not meAsImpl? i tried this iside the log state...... %@, MeAsImpl..but it did not work

Comment: Use `%p` instead of `%@` to show the memory address.

Comment: i tried 
        MeAsImpl *meAsImpl = [[MeAsImpl alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"= %p", MeAsImpl); but this code is not compilable and i receive error:unexpected interface name MeAsImpl:expected expression..please let m ekknow how to solve it

Comment: Note that `alloc` sometimes does not return a new object and `init` sometimes does return a new object.